# Cannot cast cell as Custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I made a custom cell but it's not getting called or casted.

I tried different ways of calling the identifier, registering the cell, and nothing worked, I've got an example project that it's working and I have it exactly the same. So I don't know what could be causing this.

Currently these are my functions. Debugging, I found out that it never enters the if condition inside the `cellForRowAt` so therein lies the problem, but can't figure out what's causing it.

```
func registerCell() {
        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: FAQTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: FAQTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FAQTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        if let cell = cell as? FAQTableViewCell {
            cell.preguntaLabel.text = arrayTitulo[indexPath.row] as? String
            cell.respuestaLabel.text = arrayDesc[indexPath.row] as? String
        }

        return cell
    }
```

I checked everything, the .xib of the cell, the cell.swift the controller.swift, everything, it's all matching. I don't know what else to do.

`FAQTableViewCell`:

```
import AEAccordion

final class FAQTableViewCell: AccordionTableViewCell {

    static let reuseIdentifier = "FAQTableViewCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var preguntaLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var respuestaLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: Override

    override func setExpanded(_ expanded: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setExpanded(expanded, animated: animated)

        if animated {
            UIView.transition(with: detailView, duration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.detailView.isHidden = !expanded
            }, completion: nil)
        } else {
            detailView.isHidden = !expanded
        }
    }

    private func toggleCell() {
        detailView.isHidden = !expanded
    }
}
```

FIXED IT: I just removed the .xib and made the custom cell inside the 
TableViewController on Main.storyboard

Comment: "UINib(nibName: FAQTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier": .xib name and reuseIdentifier are the same? Could you print cell?

Comment: Yes sir, they are the same.

Comment: force it and attach the crash here `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FAQTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FAQTableViewCell`

Comment: It is entering `cellForRowAt`, what it is not entering is the `if` so it just returns an `UITableViewCell` instead of `FAQTableViewCell`

Comment: `Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x119dffaa0) to 'TelemedIOS.FAQTableViewCell' (0x1105d8688).`

Comment: What code are you using to implement `FAQTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier`?

Comment: Added!.........

Comment: @DonMag Do you have any other prototype cells in the view controller? Where do you call `registerCell` method?

Comment: @Bayehx Don't you need to use the cell in multiple view controllers?

Comment: Nope, just this one :)

Comment: @Bayehx you were using the same indentifier for xib file and the prototype cell in storyboard. Thats why it was failing

Comment: @Bayehx If the issue is solved, delete the question

Answer (score 0):

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x119dffaa0) to 'TelemedIOS.FAQTableViewCell' (0x1105d8688)

You need to assign the class name `FAQTableViewCell` to cell in xib

[image]

Comment: Where? How? Thank you for your help

Comment: still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In Identity Inspector, below Custom Class Inherit Module from Target was unchecked, after checking it again, it was cast perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

According to the debbugging fact "I found out that it never enters the if in cellForRowAt".

Check the returned vale of `func tableView(_: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection _: Int) -> Int` is != Zero

and

the value of `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` only if it is implemented as that its default is 1 if not implemented

Answer (score -1):

Please check cell is nil or not. If cell is nil then remove .xib file from the target and add once again.

[image]

Comment: Nope, that's not it.

Comment: cell is nil or anything else. Please print that. Also check datasource and delegate for tableView. Are using multiple tableviews in single controller?